# Enumerate through array of structs

Tags: swift, swift2

Take a look at this code:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

var array = [Person(name: "John", age: 10), Person(name: "Apple", age: 20), Person(name: "Seed", age: 30)]

//for item in array { item.name = "error: cannot assign to property: 'item' is a 'let' constant" }
array[0].name = "Javert" //work fine.
```

I'm trying to change property's value of a struct inside a loop.

Of course I can change `Person` to `class` and it works just fine. However, I don't understand why `item` is a `le`.

Oh, I just figured this out, `for item in...` just created an copied of actual object inside `array`, that means it is automatically declared as a `let` constant.

So that's why I cannot change its properties value.

My question is, beside changing `Person` to `class`, how can I change `Person`'s properties inside a loop ?

---

Edit:

Thank to @Zoff Dino with the original `for index in 0..<array.count` answers.

However, this is just a simplified question.

What I want to archive is using higher-order functions with array of structs, like:

`array.each { item in ... }.map { item in ... }.sort { } ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old school `for i in ...` will do the job just fine:

```
for i in 0..<array.count {
    array[i].name = "..."
}
```

**Edit**: higher order function you said? This will sort the array descendingly based on `age`:

```
var newArray = array.map {
        Person(name: "Someone", age: $0.age)
    }.sort {
        $0.age > $1.age
    }

print(newArray)
```

Comment: Ya, thank you, I forgot that :D But this is just a simplified question. What I want to archive is using higher-order functions with array of structs, like: `array.each { item in ... }.map { item in ... }.sort { } ...`

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to change some properties of the elements you can use `map` and return a mutated copy of it:

```
array.map{ person -> Person in
    var tempPerson = person
    tempPerson.name = "name"
    return tempPerson
}.sort{ ... }
```

Comment: @PhamHoan Considering performance I should be very efficient since structs/value types can be copied very fast. A slightly more efficient version would be a `for in` loop over the indices and mutate the elements directly because no additional array has to be created. So for small arrays I wouldn't consider performance too much.

Comment: @adnako Thank you. I've updated my solution. The reason was that Swift 2.2 disallows `var` parameters.